# Adding options dynamically to Bootstrap searchable select

Tags: bootstrap-4, thymeleaf, bootstrap-selectpicker, select-options

When I tried to add option dynamically to Bootstrap searchable select it is adding outside the select. Please see the screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

How to properly add option dynamically to Bootstrap searchable select

This is my code

```
<div class="row form-group">                                                                                    
    <select class="col form-control selectpicker supplierSelect" data-live-search="true"                        
            title="Select Supplier..." data-size="5">                                                           

        <option th:each="supplier : ${suppliers}" th:value="${supplier.id}" th:text="${supplier.name}"></option>
    </select>                                                                                                   
    &nbsp;                                                                                                      
    <button type="button" class="btn mb-1 btn-rounded btn-outline-info"                                         
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addSupplier"><span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </span>             
    </button>                                                                                                   
</div>
```

This is how I add data

```
document.querySelector(domStrings.saveSupplierButton).addEventListener('click', function () {                   
    const data = JSON.stringify(uiController.getSupplierData());                                                
    console.log(data);                                                                                          
    const url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname+":"+window.location.port+"/supplier";
    const otherParams = {                                                                                       
        headers: {"content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF8"},                                            
        body: data,                                                                                             
        method: "POST"                                                                                          
    };                                                                                                          
    fetch(url, otherParams)                                                                                      
        .then(data=>{return data.json()})                                                                        
        .then(data => {                                                                                         
            console.log(data);                                                                                  
            let template = '<option value="{optVal}">{text}</option>';                                          
            template = template.replace('{optVal}',data['id']).replace('{text}',data['name']);                  
            $(domStrings.supplierSelect).append($.parseHTML(template));                                         
            $(domStrings.supplierSelect).selectPicker('refresh');                                               
            //fixme                                                                                             
        })                                                                                                       
        .catch(error=>console.log(error))                                                                       
});
```

but this is not working. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you receive some stack trace after try to fetch the data? Also is useful to specify that is implementing bootstrap-select in the example.

Comment: i am getting the data properly, problem is when i add the item to the select

Answer (score 1):

First check if the incoming data is in the adequate format. Asumming this, i would focus on the technique used to generate the `option` tags after receive new data. Currently is setting a variable with a string each time the data is getted, replacing it with the new values and appending to the DOM using `parseHTML`. It is possible to reduce it using ES6 String Literals and the `$` method:

```
$select.append($(`<option value="${value}">${text}</option>`));
```

I made a simple example concept of this: https://codepen.io/geekzolanos-dev/pen/bGdgvqq

Comment: that was a typo, instead of "selectPicker" i sould use 'selectpicler' and also changed the class name as id